# Prove that $x^2 \bmod 29$ isn't unique and $x^3 \bmod 29$ is

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I have a cryptographic question. First, you have the alphabet and space, comma and point and you translates it to numbers ($a=0,b=1,...,z=25,space=26,comma=27,point=28$). Then, you have to find a encryption that makes every answer unique, so every number from 0 to 28 gives a number and the outputs aren't the same .
There are two encryption strategies given and I have to prove that they are working (or not) and thus give a unique output (or not).

1) You raise the number of the letter you have to encrypt to the power of two and take the $\bmod  29 $ of that number, so the formula is: $$number^2 \equiv a \bmod29$$ and a is different for every number you put in. You have to prove that this isn't true because $$14^2 \bmod29 \equiv 15^2\bmod29$$ How can you prove it instead of just giving an example where it isn't true?

2) You raise the number to the power three and then take $\bmod29$, so the formula is: $$number^3 \equiv b \bmod29$$ and b is unique for every input. You have to prove this is true.

Are there numbers (f.e. primes) you put in the $\bmod$ for which this is always true: $$number^2 \equiv a \bmod x$$$$number^3 \equiv b \bmod x$$$$(0 \leqslant number < x)$$ and a and b are unique?

Comment: if $n^2\equiv a \bmod x$ then $(-n)^2\equiv a \bmod x$; $1^3\equiv2^3\bmod7$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner There are only positive numbers

Comment: @BOB $-n\equiv29-n\mod{29}$.

Comment: so call it $x-n$ instead of $-n$

Comment: for cubes modulo prime $x$, it depends if $3|x-1$

Comment: $(n-1)^2\equiv 1^2 \bmod n$

Comment: Because $3\nmid (29-1)$ cubing is injective (hence also bijective) modulo $29$. OTOH if $3\mid (p-1)$, then cubing is a three-to-one mapping. All because the non-zero residue classes form a multiplicative group of order $p-1$ that is known to be cyclic.

Comment: $(n^3)^{19}\equiv n^{57}\equiv n\bmod 29$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner  Providing the inverse is a good idea :-)

Comment: "How can you prove it instead of just giving an example where it isn't true" is a bit of a strange thing to ask... Really, any disproof of a "for all" statement *has* to take the form of a counterexample. PS: The response you're getting here is probably overwhelmingly theoretical. It would probably be helpful for you to get to grips with modular arithmetic (eg Fermat's Little Theorem) and functions (injective, bijective, etc) by a book or some other resource.

Comment: BOB, do learn about [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). You seem to use `mod` as an operation calculating the remainder. That will stall your progress and limits your understanding. Learn about congruences. To students of algebra `mod` is *a comparison operator*. That way of thinking frees you up to use other representatives of the residue classes. Such as $15\equiv -14 \pmod{29}$. Obviously $(-14)^2=14^2$ (as integers), so this *immediately implies that* $15^2\equiv 14^2$.

Comment: @Jyrki What do you mean by "mod is comparison operator"? What is your definition of a comparison operator? Quite puzzling. Maybe you meant something else. To me, mod is an operator that reduces to *normal form*.

Comment: @BillDubuque and to me modular multiplication is  a mapping of a torus to an integer interval ... we can all look at things differently ... okay just a silly example of a representation.

Comment: @BillDubuque A comparison operator in the sense that it returns a boolean value. Either $a$ and $b$ are congruent modulo $m$ or they are not. I have had some success teaching "algebraists" view of `mod` to telcomm engineers and/or programmers by declaring that $a\equiv b\pmod m$ means the same thing as the C-snippet $a\% m == b\% m$. Surely that looks like a comparison. Granted, that is inaccurate as it only works if all the variables are positive (the remainder operation called `mod` typically copies the sign of the dividend).

Comment: @Jyrki Oh, I thought your were talking about mod the *operator*, but on second reading (with hindsight) I see that you segued into the congruence *relation*. What misled me is your use of "operator" (in "comparison operator") for what is really an (equivalence) relation. That abuse of language may be common in CS but much less so in math.

Comment: Conceding the point about abusing language, @BillDubuque :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\pm1)^2 \equiv 1$ shows that $x^2 \bmod 29$ isn't unique. This works for every modulus greater than $2$.

$(n^3)^{19}\equiv n\bmod 29$ shows that $x^3 \bmod 29$ is unique:
$$
x^3 \equiv y^3 \bmod 29
\implies
x \equiv (x^3)^{19} \equiv (y^3)^{19} \equiv y \bmod 29
$$
This works for every modulus $m$ such that $\gcd(3,\phi(m))=1$.

Comment: Why do you raise it to the power of 19? And why does this works?

Comment: @BOB, because $3 \cdot 19 \equiv 1 \bmod 28$ and $\phi(29)=28$.

Comment: And why is it unique?

Comment: @BOB, see my edited answer.